# Best practice socket.io to broadcast message

Tags: database, node.js, web-services, sockets, socket.io

Currently we're trying to write an app to do a health check to multiple database environments(MSSQL, DB2, Oracle). A webservice is already written to do a health check query, which returns a response time.

I think that instead of a web client hooked up to the webservice to return the database status, use a node socket.io server to do a run the webservice and push the results to all the webclients will be better because the overhead of the health check databases will be minimal(in the case of 50 people using the web app at the same time, only 1 webservice call will be made every 5 seconds to do the health check instead of 50 webservice requests at the same time). In that way, if the databases should not be effected in any way even if 1 million people are using the web app. (It'll bring down the node server though.)

Here's the socket side of the code. I'm new to node and socket. My next step is to record the results in a local mongodb and just broadcast the changes (response time only) instead of everything to reduce network traffic and possible graphing the historical results. I was wondering if it's possible for socket.io to disconnect if the client has multiple tabs on it's browser and the web app is not "in focused" and reconnect to the socket once the tab is being focused again.

Just wondering is this a good way or is there a better way to accomplish my goal?
Also, is it a good idea to put my web app in the same server as the node socket server as well or it will be better to separate them?

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3030);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var allClients = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    allClients.push(socket.client.id);
    console.log(allClients);
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        var i = allClients.indexOf(socket.client.id);
        console.log(allClients[i] + ' is disconnect!');

        delete allClients[i];
        allClients = allClients.filter(function(e){return e}); 
    });
});

var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

var job = new CronJob({
    cronTime: "*/5 * * * * *",
    onTick: function() {

        var request = require("request");
        request({
            url: "dbhealthcheck.json",
            method: "GET",
            timeout: 10000,
            json:true,
            followRedirect: true,
            maxRedirects: 10,
            pool: false
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            sendUpdates(body);
        });
    },
    start: true
});
job.start();

function sendUpdates(updates) {
    io.sockets.emit('updates', updates);
}
```